Sum of 4-th powers of roots of $x^4-2x^3+3x^2+3 = 0$
The task is: find the sum of 4-th powers of complex roots of an equation: $x^4-2x^3+3x^2+3 = 0$.
I did it the dumb way.
Due to Vieta's formulas 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3+ x_4 = 2 = \sigma_1 \\
x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4 = 3 = \sigma_2\\
x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4 = 0 = \sigma_3\\
x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 3 = \sigma_4$
$(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^4 = \sigma_1^4 = \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4+4\sum_{i, j =1\\i \neq j}^4x_i^3x_j+6\sum_{i, j =1\\i \neq j}^4x_i^2x_j^2 + 12 \sum_{i, j, k =1\\i \neq j \neq k}^4x_i^2x_jx_k+24x_1x_2x_3x_4 = \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4 + 4\sigma_2\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2+6\sigma_2^2 - 4\sigma_1\sigma_3 + 4\sigma_4 = \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4 + 4(\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2)\sigma_2+6\sigma_2^2 - 4\sigma_1\sigma_3 + 4\sigma_4 \\
\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4 = \sigma_1^4 - (4(\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2)\sigma_2+6\sigma_2^2 - 4\sigma_1\sigma_3 + 4\sigma_4) = 16 - (4(4-6)\cdot 3 + 6\cdot 9 + 4 \cdot 3) = 16 - 42=-26.$
Maybe there is a simplier and quicker way to solve this? Frankly I'm not strong in symmetric polynomials. Also please tell me if my solution is wrong.

Alternatively, you can use that $\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4=2\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3-3\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2-12$, and then use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials

That looks much simplier! Please explain how did you get this...

Simply using $x_i^4-2x_i^3+3x_i^2+3 = 0$.

Oh, I'm sorry. Thank you very much, it's really nice.

It gives the same result as yours: $\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4
=2(\sigma_1^3-3\sigma_1\sigma_2+3\sigma_3)-3(\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2)-12=2(2^3-3\cdot2\cdot3+3\cdot0)-3(2^2-2\cdot3)-12=-20+6-12=-26$

I wouldn't call what you did the dumb way! The dumb way would be to calculate the roots, compute their 4th powers and then sum them. Yours is the smart way

Newton-Girard identities are helpfull but they are not easy to memorize due to its last term:
$$p_n=p_{n-1}e_1-p_{n-2}e_2+p_{n-3}e_3-...+(-1)^{n-1}ne_n$$
Here, according to your notation $\sigma_i
=e_i$. And $p_i$ are power sums.
Let's start:
$$p_1=e_1=2$$
$$p_2=p_1e_1-2e_2=-2$$
$$p_3=p_2e_1-p_1e_2+3e_3=-10$$
$$p_4=p_3e_1-p_2e_2+p_1e_3-4e_4=-26$$
